# understanding (and finding) matplotlib source code

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Here it appears that matplotlib's specgram returns 4 variables including the last which is a plot:

http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/specgram_demo.html

But here it seems there is only 3 variables returned in the tuple:

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/mlab.py#L478

Where is the missing code to generate the specgram plot? Perhaps I am just confused on the difference between pylab and matplotlib. Either way, I can't find the source.

Comment: and be warned, there is PR that does a bunch of work on this coming down the pipe.

Comment: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2522

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're confusing the function that computes the data to be plotted with the function that plots the data.

`mlab.specgram` just computes the data, while the axes method `specgram` plots it.

Have a look at: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L5786

`ipython` is very useful for things like this.  `method_name?` will display the relevant documentation and the location of the source file, while `method_name??` will display the relevant code, as well.

Understanding where the source for a matplotlib function is can be a bit confusing. Basically, anything in `matplotlib.pyplot` is auto-generated.  Essentially all of the plotting methods are actually methods of the `Axes` object.

Hopefully that gets you started. If no one else gives a better answer, I'll elaborate more in a bit, when I have more time.